# Jackson, generic list and JsonTypeInfo

Tags: java, generics, jackson, fasterxml

I currently need to serialize a list of objects. Each object implements the same interface, but I need to keep the original type of each object, so I use @JsonTypeInfo. For exemple, we have two classes, Square and Triangle, who implements IGeometry interface :

```
public class Square implements IGeometry {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int h;
    private int w;

    // get set ...
}

public class Triangle implements IGeometry {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    // get set ...
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(name = "triangle", value = Triangle.class), @Type(name = "square", value = Square.class) })
public interface IGeometry {

}
```

Now, if I do :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

IGeometry geo01 = new Triangle(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(geo01));
```

It works fine, I have the following output :

```
{
  "triangle" : {
    "x" : 1,
    "y" : 2,
    "a" : 3,
    "b" : 4,
    "c" : 5
  }
}
```

Now, because of java type erasure, if I try to make a list of IGeometry, the @JsonTypeInfo is ignored (The List is replaced by List which contains no @JsonTypeInfo). So if I do this :

```
    IGeometry geo01 = new Triangle(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    IGeometry geo02 = new Square(1, 2, 3, 4);

    List<IGeometry> geoList = new ArrayList<IGeometry>();
    geoList.add(geo01);
    geoList.add(geo02);

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(geoList));
```

I obtain this :

```
[ {
  "x" : 1,
  "y" : 2,
  "a" : 3,
  "b" : 4,
  "c" : 5
}, {
  "x" : 1,
  "y" : 2,
  "h" : 3,
  "w" : 4
} ]
```

I know there is a solution which imply to extends an ArrayList with the desired type and use it for serialization :

```
public class GeometryList extends ArrayList<IGeometry> {

}
```

And this works, but I wish to know if there is another solutions. So is there someone who already have this kind of problem and solved it differently ?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you create a JsonNode and iterate through it, then create a JsonNode for each element (then it will include the type) and when this is done, put it all together in a JsonNode and write it.